# xlxs.js how does the "l" cell hyperlink object option work

Tags: javascript, excel

Im currently using the following library to make excel documents 
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/README.md

right now two of my cells look like this

```
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 0, r: 1})] = {v: "Report Url", s: {font : {sz : "11", bold : true}}}
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 1, r: 1})] = {v: self.url, s: {font : {sz : "11"}}}
```

Which yield a row with: "Report Url" | ::really long ugly url::

The Documentation says there is an "l" option But gives no documentation as to how to use it. 
In README:

Cell object:

'::l:: cell hyperlink object (.Target holds link, .tooltip is tooltip)'

Does anyone have an exp with it, I'd like the excel to have a row with just one column that says "report url" and it would be a clickable link

All the things I tried that failed:

```
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 0, r: 1})] = {l: self.url, s: {font : {sz : "11", bold : true}}}
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 0, r: 1})] = {v: "url", l: self.url, s: {font : {sz : "11", bold : true}}}
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 0, r: 1})] = {v: Target,l: {Target :self.url}, s: {font : {sz : "11", bold : true}}}
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: 0, r: 1})] = {l: {Target :self.url}, s: {font : {sz : "11", bold : true}}}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm stuck with same right now.

Comment: As Far as I can tell it is not supported. I think the 'l' is only for reading xl docs not writing to them.

Comment: I guess so also. So gave up on XLS at this point and simply moved to RTF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is currently not implemented. See [open issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/156).

An other approach would be to use a hyperlink formula like this

```
ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({
    c: 0,
    r: 0
})] = {
    f: '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","Google")'
};
```

to achieve the same thing as soon as the [preventing issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/152) is fixed. [This patch](https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx/pull/11/commits/a7f21a3843b963c6c673115b3a3affeb3ad26283) and the [other one](https://github.com/mcsf/js-xlsx/commit/d43964564d2d455271a9348f904fe2c34e5b1a59) sadly didn't work for me.

Comment: Nothing like marking an answer as correct 10 months later :)

Comment: Yea :-). BTW: sadly the HTML cell type doesn't work on writing Excel files either.

Comment: Somehow the formula doesnt compute for me. Do you happen to know why? I just see the HYPERLINK formula in the cell in the generated file.

Comment: Because the preventing issue is not yet fixed?

Comment: @GangadharJannu no, sadly not as I didn't work on those aspects any more.

Comment: @Sandro Thanks for your prompt reply. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, wanting to link all rows in column one (except the first that is the header) with a custom link. What I did was the following (json is my array for the excel file while links is an array containig the link for each row):

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
for (let i = 1; i < json.length + 1; i++) {
    worksheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({
      c: 1,
      r: i
    })].l = { Target: links[i-1] };
}
```

That had as a result an excel file with the second column having internal custom links