# Creating hyperlink while exporting columns

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, export, xlsx

I am exporting json to xls from Angular 6 project using below function:

```
 exportAsExcelFile(jsonData: any[]): void {
    let exportObj=[{
      'Name':'ABC',
      'RollNo':'123',
      'url':'www.google.com'
      }]      


    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(exportObj);

    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    /* save to file */
    const filename = 'Sample.xlsx';

    XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
  }
```

Getting following output

[image]

Expecting below output with hyperlink.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916180
I go through all the ws and update every cells starting with "http" with *=HYPERLINK("http...", "link text")*.

(JQuery is needed for the code snippet below to work)

```
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
//Update links
jQuery.each(ws, function(cell, item) {
    if (item.v != null && item.v.toString().indexOf('http') == 0)
        ws[cell] = {f: '=HYPERLINK("' + item.v.toString() + '","link text")'};
});
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "TabName");
XLSX.writeFile(wb, "my_file.xlsx");
```